# Is there a machine for thick shredded carrots for home use (not grated)?

Tags: equipment, food-processing

You can get shredded carrots at a salad bar, and I buy bags of pre-shredded carrots at the supermarket. I want to make these at home with a machine but haven't found one. When you use a food processor, the attachment is usual a grater, similar to a coarse box grater; this makes carrot shreds that are much thinner than the thicker ones you use on a salad (or maybe for use in Vietnamese pickles, banh mi, etc).

I'm sure they use a machine to do this to make the bags available at the store, but I've only found commercial machines that can do it (example: https://www.chipsfryer.com/single-series/carrot-cutter-machine.html)

Is anyone aware of a machine that can do this for home use?

To be clear, I don't think a typical food processor grating attachment does this, nor does a box grater. I know I can use a mandoline or a knife, but I'm looking for a machine to do it in bulk, or an attachment to a food processor or stand mixer. The best idea of come up with is to try using a spiralizer and then chop up the spirals with a knife.

Comment: My food processor has two double sided discs for coarse and fine grating, and making thin and medium chips. The thin chips option is only slightly thicker than what I think you mean, and square in cross section. They may even make more discs for more options. It's a kenwood, at least 15 years old. A target dimension in some standard unit would be useful

Answer (score 7):

I think this might be the closest to what you are looking for... it's [a food processor attachment for the KitchenAid Stand Mixers](https://www.kitchenaid.com/countertop-appliances/stand-mixers/attachments/p.food-processor-attachment.ksm1fpa.html). Of course, you might look for new blades to use with your existing processor (they might offer blades that cut sticks instead of shreds).

Comment: I actually use [this one](https://www.kitchenaid.com/countertop-appliances/stand-mixers/attachments/p.fresh-prep-slicer-shredder-attachment.ksmvsa.html) and it sorta does what I think OP *might* mean.

Comment: Hm, yea the julienne blade for KitchenAid food processors (like I have) gets terrible reviews, but I think I have the slicer attachment @bruglesco linked to. I will test it out.

Comment: Let me know... curious.

Answer (score 7):

If you pick a versatile food processor, you can do it.  There's a ["fine Julienne disc"](https://www.kenwoodworld.com/en-au/products/food-preparation/food-processor-attachments/fine-julienne-disc) for various Kenwood models, for example.  This is finer than the chip-making disc I have. I also have coarse and fine grating plus slicing discs.  While these "do-everything" machines are not as good at some tasks as dedicated machines, I  think this is the best option at home if you want something motorised

Comment: Interesting, thank you, I hadn't looked into a getting another disc - good to know that might be an option. I have a KitchenAid food processor that's probably 8 or so yrs old, so I don't know if I can get one for it now. But the reviews for this one are pretty terrible: https://www.kitchenaid.com/countertop-appliances/food-processors/accessories/p.julienne-disc.kfp13jd.html

Answer (score 3):

Get a manual french fry cutter than can cut matchstick fries. 
Most common ones cut down to 1/4 inch, so if that is as small as you need, you will have tons of options.

Comment: OP wants a machine so they can do large quantities without the manual aspect.

Comment: Can you give an example? Most recipes for matchstick fries I'm seeing recommend using a mandoline slicer, which I'd prefer not to use. I have one of those, but they're pretty hard to use for carrots unless you manage to get big, thick carrots, which are rarely available where I shop.